# laravel - Delete comment by id and user id Not working

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to delete a comment by id and by user id but it's don't deleting, just page loading and nothing changed.

But if there is one comment it's deleted successfully,
if comment between more comments nothing deleted. 
Any help, please.

```
 public function commntdestroy($id)
    {
        Replies::where(['id' => $id, 'user_id' => Auth::id()])->delete();
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Route:

```
Route::delete('commentdestroy/{id}','StaffContractsController@commntdestroy');
```

I try:

```
public function commntdestroy($id)
    {
        $user_id = Auth::user();
        $replys=Replies::where('id', $id)
        ->where('user_id',$user_id);
        $replys->delete();
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Blade:

```
<form action="{{url('commentdestroy', $reply->id)}}" method="post">
 @csrf
  @method('DELETE') 
<h4 class="modal-title">Delete your Comment</h4>
<button class="btn btn-custon-four btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Comment: is `id` your primary key?? if so why you need to check against user id?? whats the logic??

Comment: because when I use id only it deletes the last comment, not for this user, but any user comment (the last comment was added)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to take the id, not the entire user object

and second you need to fetch it by calling `first()` since you only want take only 1 data

```
public function commntdestroy($id)
{
    $user_id = Auth::user(); // wrong here
    $replys=Replies::where('id', $id)
    ->where('user_id',$user_id); // wrong here
    $replys->delete();
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

correct one should be

```
public function commntdestroy($id)
{
    $user_id = Auth::id(); // 
    $replys=Replies::where('id', $id)
    ->where('user_id',$user_id)->first(); // you need to fetch the data
    //wrap if statement to check data exist or not
    if(!is_null($reply)){
        //execute if exist
        $replys->delete();
    }
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

and another advice you need to use better naming convention on your function or variable.

Comment: Thank you, but I try this nothing deleted.

Comment: Give me error `Call to a member function delete() on null`

Comment: check your database, and check the $id and $user_id you sent are existed on your database

Comment: to check you can do something like `dd('id =  . '$id . ' user_id =' . $user_id   );`  put it above $replys and then check both values are existed on database or not

Comment: if there's no data, then you can wrap it under if statement

Comment: Thank you very much, yes the database working very well if there is one comment it deleted, but the user's comment in the middle of comments it's not deleted

Comment: im not talking about that, just check with the dd to check $user_id and $id values are existed on your database, the problem is incorrect value being sent to the controller, thats why it gave you an error `delete() on null`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198763/discussion-between-ghiffari-assamar-and-hima-hima).

Answer (score 1):

There's a little bit problem with your second `commentdestroy()` function. It's taking hole user object but you don't need at all. You should use `Auth::id()` or long way, `Auth::user()->id`. Also I prefer to use named routes when using form actions. You can try something like this:

```
Route::delete('commentdestroy/{id}','StaffContractsController@commntdestroy')->name('comment.destroy');
```

```
<form action="{{ route('comment.destroy', $reply->id) }}" method="post">
 @csrf
  @method('DELETE') 
<h4 class="modal-title">Delete your Comment</h4>
<button class="btn btn-custon-four btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

others are look good but first `commentdestroy()` function looks more clean.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, very nice about naming the routs, I'll use it but about the deleting nothing changed yet.

Comment: Can you add `$fillable = [];` line to your 'Comment' model. also can you check your `$id` parameter and `Auth::id()` values that they are working properly

Comment: Ok I'll try it now

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you want to delete a single comment. The person who made that comment only can delete that. In this case your approach should be like show the delete button only to those comments those are created by the currently logged in user. Well in your current approach you can do like something like below:

```
public function commntdestroy($id)
    {
        $reply = Replies::where([
                      ['id',$id],
                      ['user_id',Auth::id()]
                      ])->first();
        if ($reply) {
            $reply->delete();
        }
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

> *You should use named route and Model name in singular form.*

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Yes I try this solution but don't delete, it's working when there is only one comment

Comment: as you are using `id` for fetching a comment, it will obviously delete one comment. do you want to delete all the comments by a single user?? make sure what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: No, I want to delete one comment not all the user comment

Comment: then it should work fine. how are you rendering comments in view? what `$reply->id` holds in the delete form?